# Mongoose .save() not saving new model with mixed type, even though calling markModified, no callback on .save()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I've been looking at previous questions, and have tried both writing markModified, ensuring my connection is not failing with mongoose.connect and ensuring that my data is populated. My code looks like the following:

index.js of the bot that is supposed to save to the database:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Item = require('../app/models/item');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydatabase');
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log('mongoose err:', err);
});

/*a lot of stuff in between */

async.parallel(itemCalls, function(err, results) {
              if (err) return console.log(err);
              var collectiveValue = 0;
              for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                var result = results[i];
                var item = result.data;
                var itemValue = parseFloat(item.hardData.price.median_price.substring(0, item.hardData.price.median_price.length-1).replace(',', '.'));
                var dbItem = new Item({
                  hardData: {
                    appid: item.hardData.appid,
                    contextid: item.hardData.contextid,
                    assetid: item.hardData.assetid,
                    classid: item.hardData.classid,
                    instanceid: item.hardData.instanceid,
                    amount: item.hardData.amount,
                    missing: item.hardData.missing,
                    price: {
                      lowest_price: item.hardData.price.lowest_price,
                      volume: item.hardData.price.volume,
                      median_price: item.hardData.price.median_price
                    }
                  },
                  softData: {
                    name: item.softData.name,
                    market_name: item.softData.market_name,
                    market_hash_name: item.softData.market_hash_name,
                    icon_url: {
                      normal: item.softData.icon_url.normal,
                      large: item.softData.icon_url.large
                    }
                  }
                });
                dbItem.markModified('hardData.price');
                dbItem.markModified('softData.icon_url');
                dbItem.markModified('hardData');
                dbItem.markModified('softData');
                console.log(dbItem);
                dbItem.save(function(err) {
                  console.log('saved item');
                  if (err) console.log(err);
                });
                offer.items_to_receive[i].value = itemValue;
                collectiveValue += itemValue;
              }
              offer.total_item_value = collectiveValue;
              offers.acceptOffer({tradeOfferId: offer.tradeofferid});
              console.log('Accepted offer ', offer.tradeofferid);
              winston.log('Accepted offer ' + offer.tradeofferid);
            });
```

and the item.js with the item model and schema that I'm including:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var itemSchema = new Schema({
    hardData: {
    appid: String,
    contextid: String,
    assetid: String,
    classid: String,
    instanceid: String,
    amount: {type: Number, default: 1},
    missing: Boolean,
    price: {
      lowest_price: {type: String, default: '0'},
      volume: {type: String, default: '0'},
      median_price: {type: String, default: '0'}
    }
  },
  softData: {
    name: String,
    market_name: String,
    market_hash_name: String,
    icon_url: {
      normal: {type: String, default: ''},
      large: {type: String, default: ''}
    }
  }
});

var Item = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema);

module.exports = Item;
```

The save is not executing somehow, as I'm not getting the callback, nor am I getting the data in the database.

Comment: I don't see any fields with the `Mixed` type in your schema, so I don't understand why you're calling `markModified`. Anyway, there's a lot of code here so try and create a [mcve] that reproduces the problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the question after making a minimal version of the two scripts together in one, whereafter it worked. The issue is, that the item.js file and the index.js had two separate mongoose connections. The problem was resolved by changing the item.js code to the following:

```js
module.exports = function(mongoose) {
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var itemSchema = new Schema({
  hardData: {
    appid: String,
    contextid: String,
    assetid: String,
    classid: String,
    instanceid: String,
    amount: {type: Number, default: 1},
    missing: Boolean,
    price: {
      lowest_price: {type: String, default: '0'},
      volume: {type: String, default: '0'},
      median_price: {type: String, default: '0'}
    }
  },
  softData: {
    name: String,
    market_name: String,
    market_hash_name: String,
    icon_url: {
      normal: {type: String, default: ''},
      large: {type: String, default: ''}
    }
  }
});
var Item = mongoose.model('Item', itemSchema);
return Item;
}
```

This means that it can be required by writing `var Item = require('/path/to/item')(mongoose)`, referencing an already existing mongoose connection.